# Is there a CDF Player for Mathematica 10? (Yes)

Tags: cdfplayer

The download page for the CDF player http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/, only shows version 9.0.1, which shows an error message when I open CDFs created with V10.

Comment: This [workaround](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60154/18476) might be helpful until version 10 is released.

Comment: yes, it's avilable in the version 10

Comment: But you won't tell us where to find it?

Comment: It is not available yet: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/332978

Comment: About a couple of weeks ago they said they would release it within a month.

Comment: I've heard that a v10 player is (hoped) to be released in the next 2-4 weeks. The delay is partly due to cloud integration. The new player will apparently bring together Free Player and Player Pro into a single install. You will install the free player and then if required you can purchase a licence to activate the Pro functionality.

Comment: This is a big strategic blunder. You have a company that is trying to create a new market and they do not sync their two most useful products to achieving that aim; their content creation product and their content consumption product.  Let's hope the lesson is learned and going forward these to will be synced.

Comment: @Kurt, can we have a decisive date when the 10.2 CDF Player be released? This is kind of important to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDF Player 10 was finally released recently:

http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/

Answer (score 2):

Its also worth noting that CDF Player 10 has had 1 update since release with no version number change - so if you downloaded it in the first week or so you should probably re-download.  On a windows machine there is about ~3k difference in file size.  This was due to issues with the plugin when using Chrome and Firefox.  On my system the file sizes were 589,746KB (older) vs 589,743KB (newer).  Note your file sizes may not be the same due to differences in FileSystem and OS.